# Can't run Unigine_Valley-1.0.run file - "archive type not supported"

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to run Unigine benchmark file and it gives me the error in title.

I also have tried doing `chmod +x` on that file, without success, as then it gives me this:

```
roope@gottaslay:~$ chmod +x Unigine_Valley-1.0.run
```

chmod: cannot access 'Unigine_Valley-1.0.run': No such file or directory

Comment: My apologies, I'm still new to this community. I'll try my best to make sure my questions come out appropriately!

Comment: I did `cd /mnt/sdc3/Downloads` as it is where I've decided to have my downloads saved and that's where I can see it in the list.

Comment: Yes after entering `cd /mnt/sdc3/Download` I typed in `./Unigine_Valley-1.0.run` and the installation started appropriately and it works as supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I opened terminal and wrote in `cd /mnt/sdc3/Downloads` to access my Downloads folder where I had downloaded the file Unigine_Valley-1.0.run and then entered the file name `./Unigine_Valley-1.0.run` and my benchmark utility installation began correctly.